# Sort group item by attribute

Tags: c#, sorting, linq

I have a repository method which retrieve a list of items, for example:

```
StaffID: 250026965
Name: Abbasov Islam
FreeTextName: NULL

StaffID: NULL
Name: NULL
FreeTextName: Antonio Puccio

StaffID: 358
Name: Prosinecki Robert
FreeTextName: NULL
```

I have to sort this list in this manner:

First the items with `StaffID > 0` by Name, then the items with `StaffID == NULL` by `FreeTextName`.

In the example case:

```
StaffID: 250026965
Name: Abbasov Islam
FreeTextName: NULL

StaffID: 358
Name: Prosinecki Robert
FreeTextName: NULL

StaffID: NULL
Name: NULL
FreeTextName: Antonio Puccio
```

At the moment I am doing:

```cs
var resList = conn.Query<TeamSheetStaffPoco>("[dbo].[TList]", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
var result = resList.Where(x => x.StaffID> 0).OrderBy(y => y.Name).ToList();
result.AddRange(resList.Where(x => x.StaffID== null).OrderBy(y => y.FreeTextName).ToList());
```

It works, but I am not sure if exist a more concise and elegant mode to to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3(v=vs.110).aspx) to sort the the items.

```
class TeamSheetStaffPocoComparer : IComparer<TeamSheetStaffPoco> {

    public int Compare(TeamSheetStaffPoco a, TeamSheetStaffPoco b) {

        if (a.StaffID == null && b.StaffId == null)
        {
            return a.FreeTextName.CompareTo(b.FreeTextName);
        }

        if (a.StaffID > 0 && b.StaffID > 0) 
        {
            return a.Name.CompareTo(b.Name);
        }

        return a.StaffID > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    }

 }
```

Then you can simplify the last two lines to

```
var result = resList.OrderBy(x => x, new TeamSheetStaffPocoComparer()).ToList();
```

Also, you can now reuse the comparison class elsewhere too if you wish.